# How to show Custom Wordpress Menu inline at top?

Tags: css, wordpress

I just integrated custom wordpress menu, and menu is shown at top, where i want to be shown, but i have issue with allign it inline. I inserted menu into header.php file from theme in this way:

```
<?wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'top-menu', 'container_class' => 'top_menu_class' ) ); ?>
```

Menu is called `top-menu` and its shown at top, but in horisontal line. I want to be vertical like main menu. Because menu have class selector i tryed to assign CSS rules to CSS class, but seems do not change it:

```
.top_menu_class {
display: inline-block;
}
```

but dont seems to make any change. Any help [here](http://fibrotalksolutions.com)? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css

```
.top_menu_class,ul#menu-coping-nutrition{
float:left;
width:100%;
}

ul#menu-coping-nutrition li {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to change color of links into top menu? i tryed to add: `color:#fff;` to class but seems not make changes.

Comment: you need to target anchor

Comment: For example? what anchor?

Comment: ul#menu-coping-nutrition li a { color : #fff; }

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to set the parent container to 100% it is limited to 60px width at the moment, after that you can easily set your list item to inline-block and it will all align nicely in a horizontal line.

```
.top_menu_class {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu-item {
    display: inline-block;
}
```